# Ionic 3 problem with getting data out of api

Tags: api, http, ionic-framework, get

My Api works fine i tested with postman i can get all my data but when i try 2 use this data in my frontend (ionic) then i only get undefined back. 
my code in the service

```
testdata2(): Observable<Players[]>{
  console.log("gedrukt testdata2")
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseApi}/player`)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .catch(this.handleError);

}
```

and in the page

```
 Check6(){
      this.service.testdata2().subscribe(data => this.PlayerData = data);
      console.log(this.PlayerData);
    }
```

Comment: You `console.log` is outside of `subscribe` method. Are you getting any error in console?

Comment: only thing I  see is 'undefined'

Comment: And what do you see in chrome console's network tab? Are you getting any data?

Comment: first the request are pending for a minute and then it says net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: but thanks never looked at the network tab maybe i can solve it myself

Answer (score 0):

Since its an async call, the `console.log` should be inside of `subscribe` method like -

```
 Check6() {
  this.service.testdata2().subscribe((data) => {
    this.PlayerData = data;
    console.log(this.PlayerData);
   });
}
```